# Change parent menu item to display sub-menu item on hover instead of onclick

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, wordpress-theming

I have the following situation:

I am developing this WordPress theme using **BootStrap** CSS framework: http://onofri.org/WP_BootStrap/

As you can see, in the header, I have an horizontal **main menu** that contains the **"Super Voice"** main voice. Clicking on it appear to you the submenu that contain **"Sub Voice"**

As you can see to see the sub menu I have to click on the super voice on my main menu.

To create this menu I have use the wp_bootstrap_navwalker class inserting the wp_bootstrap_navwalker.php file putting it into my theme folder.

This class is downlodable here: https://github.com/twittem/wp-bootstrap-navwalker

I want to change this behavior so as to display the submenu passing the mouse on the super voice and not clicking on it (in the same way as work the main menu of this website: http://www.erusma.org )

My problem is that I can't understand where (and how) is definied the settings that specify to open the sub menu when the user click on the super voice. I think that this is a JavaScript settings (but I am not sure)

Do you have some ideas about how locate this settings?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 0):

I personally recommend removing the bootstrap nav menu and instead using wordpress's native menu:
http://codex.wordpress.org/WordPress_Menu_User_Guide

this might save you some time and you can always consider revising your menu implementation further down the line.

Comment: mmm but it allows me to create sub menu?

Comment: yes, you can use the drag and drop to implement it as a sub menu.  Once you are in the wordpress menu area in the backend, you will see it is very easy to use.

Comment: I have insert it into my local website version using <?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?> and now I see the menu as an UL, what can I do? create the HTML\CSS structure?

Comment: Are you not able to use the wordpress admin backend to edit or create your menu? or is there a reason you are editing the php files directly?